# NoClassDefFoundError on org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockReset

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-mvc, junit

I am trying to write Junit for my Spring Boot REST application, but my test is failing with NoClassDefFoundError. Although, the jar is present in the classpath. I have tried multiple different annotations,but it is still failing at same place

Following are my classs

**Application.java**

package com.test;

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(Application.class);
}
}
```

**BusinessServiceController.java**

```
package com.test;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/business_services_WS")
public class BusinessServiceController {

Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BusinessServiceController.class);

/**
 * 3.3.0 Request System Automation Limits [RSP-NSR]
 * @author eaggatu
 */
@RequestMapping(value = "/number")    
@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<String> numberQueryResponse(@RequestBody String responseObj) {
    log.info(responseObj);
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body("Number Search Query called");
}
}
```

**Test Class**

```
package com.test;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.AutoConfigureMockMvc;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTest;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;

import com.test.BusinessServiceController;

/*@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@SpringBootTest(classes={Application.class})
*/
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(controllers = BusinessServiceController.class)
// @SpringBootTest(classes={Application.class})
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class CallBackResponseSimulatorTest {

@Autowired
private WebApplicationContext context;
@Autowired
private MockMvc mvc;
/*
 * @Before public void setup(){ mvc =
 * MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(context).build(); }
 */

@Test
public void callNumberSearchServiceSuccess() throws Exception {
    this.mvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/CallBackResponseSimulator/business_services_WS/number")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8).content("Hello! World"))
            .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.content().json("Number Search Query called"))
            .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk());
}
}
```

**Stack Trace**

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.<init>()V from class org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockReset
at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockReset.<clinit>(MockReset.java:56)
at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.beforeTestMethod(ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.java:45)
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.beforeTestMethod(TestContextManager.java:269)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockReset
at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.afterTestMethod(ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.java:50)
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.afterTestMethod(TestContextManager.java:319)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:94)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

**Build.gradle**

```
        buildscript {
        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.4.1.RELEASE")
        }
    }

    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'eclipse'
    apply plugin: 'idea'
    apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
    apply plugin: 'war'

    jar {
        baseName = 'gs-rest-service'
        version =  '0.1.0'
    }

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }

    sourceCompatibility = 1.8
    targetCompatibility = 1.8

    dependencies {
        compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.7'
        compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")

        providedRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'    
        compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
        compile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        compile group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-core', version: '2.2.7'
    }
```

Comment: Earlier test dependencies were having scope testCompile, I changed it to find a workaround, but din't work

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Remove junit and mockito dependencies spring-boot-starter-test will provide the rights versions of these dependencies.

spring-boot-starter-test will add junit:4.12 and mockito:2.2.29

Comment: Hey! Thanks Issam, I removed Mockito and Junit dependencies and that error disappeared. Although, Test din't pass. But that is another issue :)

Comment: Glad it helped. Plz accept the answer. Create a new SO and share it if you want me to help fixing test issue

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to remove the test execution listeners of your test class, annotating the class with @TestExecutionListeners. 
Like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner::class)
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("integration")
@TestExecutionListeners()
class MyIntegrationTest {
...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For me the answer to this error was to insert the following TestExecutionListeners declaration at the top of my test case.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@TestExecutionListeners(listeners = {SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class, ServletTestExecutionListener.class})
public class MyUnitTest {
```